# How to dynamically present text on application view?

Tags: iphone, lines, label

I'm working on an app which look like a paper block which keeps score for one game, when user types the score and taps Insert, I want to that score to become visible on that paper block.

Let's say that there could be maximum od 12 lines of score on the paper, and the user must type those 12 lines, what is the best way to display one line of score at the time?
(He enters the score and there is only one score in the first line, he types the score again, and the second score appears in the second line of the paper)

Should I create 12 labels in a row in the nib, and after users types the first score it will display in the first label, after he types the second score it will display in the second label and so on...

Is there an easier way to do this? Because I can't think of any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and update it dataSource array.

Comment: Can I have two table views in one xib?

Comment: Yes you can, just drag and drop two tableView's.